# esper query is half executed - only part of it is actually running

Tags: esper

we have a strange issue, where esper query is only partial executed...

select cseShutDownAlarm.INSTANCEID as INSTANCEID, swtDownAlarm.source 
from Alarm(severity.getValue()=5, eventType.getValue() = 'SWT_SWITCH_DOWN').win:time(60 sec) as swtDownAlarm,
sql:stormdb['select id as INSTANCEID, source as SOURCE 
from Alarm where EVENTTYPE_VALUE =\'cseShutDownNotify\' and source = ${swtDownAlarm.source} and severity !=5'] as cseShutDownAlarm,
sql:stormdb['insert into wcsdba.dyinggasp (parameter, value) VALUES (\'cseShutDownAlarm.SOURCE\', ${cseShutDownAlarm.SOURCE}) '],
sql:stormdb['insert into wcsdba.dyinggasp (parameter, value) VALUES (\'swtDownAlarm.source\', ${swtDownAlarm.source}) '] where swtDownAlarm.source = cseShutDownAlarm.SOURCE

and in the DB, we see that:

SQL> /

PARAMETER                                                                           VALUE

---

cseShutDownAlarm.SOURCE                                                            172.16.148.48
cseShutDownAlarm.SOURCE                                                            172.16.148.48

SQL>

but second source (swtDownAlarm.source) is not printed...
If I switch the order then the other one will be inserted only.

any reason why it does not execute both inserts? also the rest of the condition is not checked... as the source on both are identical, but condition not fulfilled.

Thanks,
fcbman

Comment: This is too hard for me to look at without seeing the event that arrives and without have the rows in the database and without knowing exactly what is expected as output. You need to write a test class and instructions how to set up a database. This is for the current version of Esper, if not make sure to test against the current 8.6.0 version ascertaining it is not a bug already fixed.

Comment: Joins are meant to be the place for event stream joins against SQL database for purpose of querying. The "insert into" isn't a query and would never return rows.

Comment: ...and if an inner join doesn't return rows it ends early (outer join would be right then)

Answer (score 0):

Joins are meant to be the place for event stream joins against SQL database for purpose of querying. The "insert into" isn't a query and would never return rows. And if an inner join doesn't return rows it ends early (outer join would be right then)